Move resource from one region to another region
I have tried to move a resource from one region to another region but when I'm trying to Azure resource mover to move a particular resource I'm getting a message saying that it is unsupported. Is it possible to move ?
Move resource from one region to another

Can you share more details about what resource shows the error?

Was trying to move app service resource to a different region and message says that 1 resource have been removed from your orginal selection as they cannot move to the destination

Are you trying to move the resource using Portal or any other approach. @reelMedia

Using azure portal


Move resource from one region to another region:

Moving a resource from one region to another region is supported for few Azure resources such as VM's and function apps.
Refer MS Doc to verify what are all the resources can be moved across the regions globally.
If it is applicable for resource movement, you can be able to view it beside the location tab under Azure resource as shown below.

As mentioned in the blog by @rebeladm, Azure resource mover supports the below resource types for regional movement.

• Azure VMs and associated disks
• NICs
• Availability sets
• Azure virtual networks
• Public IP addresses
• Network security groups (NSGs)
• Internal and public load balancers
• Azure SQL databases and elastic pools

As a workaround, the resources which are not supported to move from one to another region can be marked as a zone redundant when creating and deploying it.
Enable zone redundancy
Check here for zone migration availability for the azure resources.
As given above, I have created a VM, its dependencies and tried to move it from one region to another as shown below. It worked for me as expected.

You can also use New-AzResourceMoverMoveCollection PowerShell command to move resources across regions.
PowerShell: New-AzResourceMoverMoveCollection
